# Include math equation with ocamldoc

Tags: documentation, latex, ocaml

I would like to include equations in a documentation generated with ocamldoc. I am using a small (bat) script :

```
ocamldoc -latex maths.ml 
pdflatex ocamldoc.out
```

where maths.ml contains the following comments :

```
(** "Given a list of indices \\( v \\)  and a vector of weights \f$ w \f$, this returns $ sum_iw_{v_i} $"*)
let dot_product indices weights = [...]
```

However, the only thing produced in the pdf file is :

```
val dot_product : int list -> float array -> float
"Given a list of indices \\( v \\) and a vector of weights \f$ w \f$, this returns $ sum_iw_
$"
```

I tried various ways to indicate the equations ($, \f$,  \( ) but none of these were identified. Is there a specific way to indicate equations for them to be recognized by ocamldoc ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [target specific formatting](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/ocamldoc.html#sss%3Atarget-specific-syntax):

```
{%latex: ... %}
```

Note that in general `ocamldoc` documentation is rendered to HTML rather than PDFs. So I would not take advantage of that directive and/or care for the HTML output. For sub/super scripts the [ocamldoc language](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/ocamldoc.html#sec340) supports them directly. For HTML specific output simply do

```
{%html: ... %}
```